# Pointwise convergence; a problem I found on a Ph.D Prelim exam

Tags: real-analysis

> Given $f_n = \dfrac{e^{nx}}{e^{nx}+e^{-nx}}$. Find the pointwise convergence on $\mathbb{R}$.

I found this problem on some Ph.D analysis exam. I don't recall the whole problem, but I thought i take a whack at it.

$f_n = 1/2$ for $x = 0$ and $f_n = \dfrac{e^{2nx}}{e^{2nx}+1}$ if $x \neq 0$

Taking the limit gives $$f = \begin{cases}
1/2 & \text{ if } x= 0\\ 
1 & \text{ if } x > 0 \\ 
1 & \text{ if } x < 0 
\end{cases}$$.

I also verified that $\lim_{n \to \infty}|f - f_n| = 0$. This implies it is uniform convergent too right?

Comment: What happens to the limit when x is negative? Is it still 1?

Comment: Oh shoot I had totally forgotten and neglected the negatives.

Comment: How did you get $1/2$ when $x<0$?

Comment: Because I wrote down the wrong function on my piece of paper... - I had $\frac{e^{n}}{1 + e^{2n}}$ instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking for example $\,x<0\iff -x>0\,$ , we get

$$f_n(x)=\frac{e^{2nx}}{1+e^{2nx}}=\frac1{1+e^{-2nx}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

so the limit is *not* the constant function $\,f(x)=1\,$ , but rather

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&,\;\;\;x<0\\{}\\\frac12&,\;\;\;x=0\\{}\\{}\\1&,\;\;\;x>0\end{cases}$$

so that the limit function isn't continuous and thus the convergence cannot be uniform.

Comment: Oh shoot, I found my mistake. I let $x = -u$, but I took forgot about the negative sign and took the wrong limit.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Divide the numerator and denominator by $e^{nx}$ to get $$f_n=\frac{1}{1+e^{-2nx}}$$

This is easier to work with. Also, in regards to your last comment, recall that the uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous. Do you see how to apply this statement?